# Add real device as platform for running cordova application

Tags: android, apache, mobile, cordova

i'm using apache cordova to develop an application.

As we all know, we build the project (in windows) by:

> cordova build android

and run it in an emulator by:

> cordova emulate android

How do I use an actual device instead of running it through an emulator? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Refer the documentation: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html

```
cordova run android
```

Comment: I tried this one, but it says No started emulators found, starting an emulator. And then again it runs a created AVD.

Comment: Have you setup the device for testing? Installed required drivers and enabled USB debugging on the device? What does running `adb devices` on command line say?

Comment: when i delete the avd i created,, I see "error: no emulator images <avds> found, if you would like to create..." instructs me to create an emulator

Comment: Please see comment above. Maybe you have not setup the device for testing.

Comment: yeah i forgot usb debug to on :)